# Mysql "where rand()" performance

Tags: mysql, performance, random

I'm trying to pick random articles from my database, where high rating articles have a higher chance of getting picked

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE RAND()>0.9  ORDER BY rating  DESC LIMIT 3
```

My question is:
 Will it random the whole table, or just until it finds 3 articles that random a number higher then 0.9

Comment: It will only select 3 articles that have a `rand() > 0.1`.  But you don't want random records. You want to order them by rating?

Comment: I know it will select 3, but does it have to random the whole table?

in this query high rating articles have a higher chance of getting picked
beacause the first 10 has 10%, and it goes down after that...

Answer (score 0):

If you have `INDEX(rating)`, that query will *probably* fetch 3 or 4 (3/(1-0.1)) rows before finding the 3.

But that does not give you "high rating articles have a higher chance of getting picked" at all.  It merely gives you a random 90% of the highest ranking rows.

This might give you what you want, but with a full table scan:

```
SELECT *
    FROM articles
    ORDER BY rating * RAND() DESC
    LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: I've fixed my mistake. It's 0.9 not 0.1